# add eduPerson schema to ApacheDS

Tags: ldap

I am working on an application for my University where I will be connected to the university's identity service. As part of the development effort, I am going to need to setup a test ldap server that I can use for testing. I am planning on using ApacheDS for this test server.

The University uses the eduPerson schema as part of there system. I will need to have this schema loaded onto my test ApacheDS system as well. How might I do this?

#### References

- [eduPerson Schema](http://www.internet2.edu/products-services/trust-identity/eduperson-eduorg/)
- [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache DS stores schema elements as entries in DIT under ou=schema. That means you can add/import a new schema into DIT directly.

The eduPerson schema is published here: 
https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/macedir/Apache+Directory+Server+eduPerson

Pick it up and save it as a .ldif file and import it into into Apache DS using the DS Studio. Read "Importing the schema" section in this link:
http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.3.1-adding-schema-elements.html

**Note:** To avoid any discrepancies, you can export the eduPerson schema from the university DS as .ldif and import it into your test DS.